# Enforce uniqueness within a date range or based on the value of another column

Tags: mariadb

I have a table with a large amount of data; moving forward, I would like to enforce uniqueness for a given column in this table. However, the table contains a large amount of rows where that column is non-unique. I am not able to delete or alter these rows.

Is it possible to enforce uniqueness over a given date range, or since a specific date, or based on the value of another column (or something else like that) in MariaDB?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273) (don't just change your question to "How").
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Without any data example and scenario illustration, it's hard to know. If you can update your question with those information, please do.

*"Is it possible to enforce uniqueness over a given date range, or since a specific date, or based on the value of another column (or something else like that) in MariaDB?"*

If by "enforce" you mean to create a new column then populate it with unique identifier, then yes it is possible. If what you really mean is to **generate** a unique value based on other column, that's also possible. Question is, how *unique* do you want it to be?

Is it like this unique?

| column1 | column2 | column3 | unique_val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-02 | ABC | DEF | 1 |
| 2021-02-02 | CBD | FEA | 1 |
| 2021-02-03 | BED | GER | 2 |
| 2021-02-04 | ART | TOY | 3 |
| 2021-02-04 | ZSE | KSL | 3 |

Whereby if it's the same date (on column1), it should have the same unique value regardless of `column2` & `column3` data.

Or like this?

| column1 | column2 | column3 | unique_val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-02 | ABC | DEF | 1 |
| 2021-02-02 | CBD | FEA | 2 |
| 2021-02-03 | BED | GER | 3 |
| 2021-02-04 | ART | TOY | 4 |
| 2021-02-04 | ZSE | KSL | 5 |

Taking all (or certain) columns to consider the unique value.

Both of the scenario above can be achieved in query without the need to alter the table, adding and populate a new column but of course, the latter is also possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `UNIQUE` index on multiple columns, where one column is `nullable`. MariaDB will see each column with `NULL` values as a different value regarding the `UNIQUE` index, even if the other column values of the `UNIQUE` index are the same. Check the MariaDB documentation [Getting Started with Indexes - Unique Index](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/getting-started-with-indexes/#unique-index):

> The fact that a `UNIQUE` constraint can be `NULL` is often overlooked. In SQL any `NULL` is never equal to anything, not even to another `NULL`. Consequently, a `UNIQUE` constraint will not prevent one from storing duplicate rows if they contain null values:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1 (a INT NOT NULL, b INT, UNIQUE (a,b));
>
> INSERT INTO t1 values (3,NULL), (3, NULL);
>
> SELECT * FROM t1;
> +---+------+
> | a | b    |
> +---+------+
> | 1 |    1 |
> | 2 |    1 |
> | 2 |    2 |
> | 3 | NULL |
> | 3 | NULL |
> +---+------+
> ```

You can create such a `UNIQUE` index on the date column you already have and a new column which indicates if the date value should be unique or not:

```
CREATE TABLE Foobar(
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    createdAt DATE NOT NULL, 
    dateUniqueMarker BIT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
    UNIQUE KEY uq_createdAt(createdAt, dateUniqueMarker)
);

INSERT INTO Foobar(createdAt) VALUES ('2021-11-04'),('2021-11-05'),('2021-11-06');

SELECT * FROM Foobar;
+----+------------+------------------------------------+
| id | createdAt  | dateUniqueMarker                   |
+----+------------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | 2021-11-04 | 0x00                               |
|  2 | 2021-11-05 | 0x00                               |
|  3 | 2021-11-06 | 0x00                               |
+----+------------+------------------------------------+

INSERT INTO Foobar(createdAt) VALUES ('2021-11-05');
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '2021-11-05-\x00' for key 'Foobar.uq_createdAt'

UPDATE Foobar SET dateUniqueMarker = NULL WHERE createdAt = '2021-11-05';

INSERT INTO Foobar(createdAt, dateUniqueMarker) VALUES ('2021-11-05', NULL);

SELECT * FROM Foobar;
+----+------------+------------------------------------+
| id | createdAt  | dateUniqueMarker                   |
+----+------------+------------------------------------+
|  1 | 2021-11-04 | 0x00                               |
|  2 | 2021-11-05 | NULL                               |
|  5 | 2021-11-05 | NULL                               |
|  3 | 2021-11-06 | 0x00                               |
+----+------------+------------------------------------+
```